# Arrays-odds and evens to determine how many of the values in the array are odd and how many are even

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to find the evens and odds of an array for practice.

Sample Data :

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 14
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2 10 20 21 23 24 40 55 60 61
```

Sample Output :

```
Odds - []
Evens - [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]

Odds - [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
Evens - [2, 4, 6, 8]

Odds - [21, 23, 55, 61]
Evens - [2, 10, 20, 24, 40, 60]
```

And here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OddsAndEvens
{
    private static int countEm(int[] array, boolean odd)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int dum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i< array.length; i++)
        {
            dum = array[i] / 2;
            if(dum == 0 )
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static int[] getAllEvens(int[] array)
    {
        int numberEvens=0;
        for(int i =0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            if(array[i]%2 ==0)
            {
                numberEvens++;
            }
        }

        int[] evens  = new int[array.length - countEm(array,false)];
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            if(array[i]%2==0)
            {
                evens[count] = array[i];
                count++;
            }
        }
        return evens;
    }

    public static int[] getAllOdds(int[] array)
    {
        int numberEvens = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                numberEvens++;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I been getting errors in my output. These errors are the fact I am  getting zeros  in my output .
I'm just starting out and I'm hoping anyone can help me.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: The code you posted looks incomplete. Also, it appears you count even numbers in `evenNumbers`, but then never use it anywhere.

Comment: Show us your `main` method or where ever you're calling these methods.

Comment: @DARKreyna I've added a working solution below, take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **main problem** comes from your `countEm` method. It is also the reason for all the **extra zeroes** behind your array. By doing minimal changes can solve these problems and make your program work.

One of the major **careless mistake** is that you used `/` instead of `%` for checking evens and odds in your `countEm` method.

1. Your `countEm` method is incomplete
2. Using wrong operator to count even/odd

Your incomplete `countEm` method now only counts the number of even number no matter the Boolean value is true or false. I've helped you implemented the complete `countEm`:

```
private static int countEm(int[] array, boolean odd)
{
    int numEven = 0;
    int numOdd = 0; 
    for(int i=0; i< array.length; i++)
        if(array[i] % 2 == 0 )   //You used / instead of % earlier!
            numEven++;
        else
            numOdd++; 

    if(odd)
        return numOdd;
    else
        return numEven; 
}
```

Make the above changes, I am **sure it will work**. Of course, you haven't complete your method for getting getAllOdds yet. Above changes will make your getAllEvens work properly.

---

**Alternatively**, for myself, I like to write it this way. I prefer shorter codes:

```
private static int countEm(int[] array, boolean odd)
{
    int numEven = 0;
    for(int i=0; i< array.length; i++)
        if(array[i] % 2 == 0 )
            numEven++;             
    return odd?array.length-numEven:numEven;
}
```

I prevent using data structures like array list because when I see such questions, I know what are the only things you are allowed to use.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new array with too many initial items - hence the zeros at the end. Your getAllEvens() method could look more like:

```
public static int[] getAllEvens(int[] array)
{
    int numberEvens = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            numberEvens++;
        }

    }

    int[] evens = new int[numberEvens]; // This has changed
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            evens[count] = array[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    return evens;
}
```

This creates a new array with exactly the number of items you are about to populate it with.

Edit: To address your comment, here is my main() method and the output from the method above.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] input =
    {
        2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14,
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
        2, 10, 20, 21, 23, 24, 40, 55, 60, 61

    };

    int[] evens = getAllEvens(input);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(evens));
}
```

Which gives

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 2, 4, 6, 8, 2, 10, 20, 24, 40, 60]
```

Comment: While i love how your code looks i still got some zeros , perhaps i missed up my odds?

Comment: @DARKreyna updated with a simple main method and sample output. The odds method should be the same, but with the `== 0` as `!= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be the best way to do that:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EvensAndOdds {

public static List<Integer> getOdds(int[] numbers){
    List<Integer> odds = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        if((numbers[i]%2) != 0){
            odds.add(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
    return odds;
}

public static List<Integer> getEvens(int[] numbers){
    List<Integer> evens = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        if((numbers[i]%2) == 0){
            evens.add(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
    return evens;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};

    List<Integer> evens = getEvens(numbers);
    List<Integer> odds = getOdds(numbers);

    System.out.println("Evens: ");
    for(Integer even: evens){
        System.out.print(even.toString() + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Odds: ");
    for(Integer odd: odds){
        System.out.print(odd.toString() + " ");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What about ;):

```
public class EvenOddSorter {

    public void sort(int[] numbers) {
       Arrays.sort(numbers,new Comparator<int>() {
           @Override
           public int compare(int i, int y) {  
               if(i % 2 == 0) 
                  return -1;
               if(y % 2 == 0) 
                  return 1;
               return 0;
           }            
       });
    }

}
```

then extract odds and evens from your array by finding the first odd number and using

```
int[] evens = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, 0, numberOfFirstOdd);
int[] odds =  Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, numberOfFirstOdd, numbers.length)
```

;)